# How to use if else to get three outcomes in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a large dataset of poultry. A subset of it looks like this:

````
>poultry
  Bird_ID weight_grams Year_weighed Alive
1 1_brown          855         2021     A
2 1_brown          850         2019     A
3 2_brown          852         2021     A
4 2_brown          848         2020     A
5 3_brown          851         2021     D
6 3_brown          850         2020     A
7 4_brown          620         2018     D
8 4_brown          580         2015     A```

I want to create a column to my poultry data frame and call it 'status'. This status column will indicate:

(i) 'New Big' if a bird used to have a weight <850 grams in one of the years it was weighed then grew to ≥850grams in another year and it has ‘A’ under Alive column, meaning it is still alive. 
(ii) 'Big' if a bird always had a weight ≥850 grams in all the years it was weighed and it has ‘A’ under Alive column, meaning it is still alive. 
(iii) 'Dead' if a bird has at least a ‘D’ under Alive column.

My desired output looks like this:

```> output    
  Bird_ID weight_grams Year_weighed Alive  Status
1 1_brown          855         2021     A     Big
2 1_brown          850         2019     A     Big
3 2_brown          852         2021     A New Big
4 2_brown          848         2020     A New Big
5 3_brown          851         2021     D    Dead
6 3_brown          850         2020     A    Dead
7 4_brown          620         2018     D    Dead
8 4_brown          580         2015     A    Dead
````

I have tried to work with dplyr pipes as follows:

```
  group_by(Bird_ID) %>%
  mutate(status = if((min(weight_grams) < 850) & (max(weight_grams) >= 850) & (Alive == "A")) 'New Big' else if ((Alive == "A") & (min(weight_grams) >= 850)) 'Big' else 'Dead')
```

Unfortunately this produces several warning messages which I don’t understand. I will be grateful for any pointers

Comment: `if` and `&`/`|` should rarely (never) be used together unless there is an `any` or `all` or some other aggregating function surrounding the `&`/`|`. This is true in `mutate` or by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `case_when` will be useful here to include multiple conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

poultry %>%
  group_by(Bird_ID) %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(
    min(weight_grams) < 850 & max(weight_grams) >= 850 & all(Alive == 'A') ~ 'New Big', 
    all(weight_grams >= 850) & all(Alive == 'A') ~ 'Big', 
    any(Alive == 'D') ~ 'Dead'
    )) %>% ungroup

#  Bird_ID weight_grams Year_weighed Alive status 
#  <chr>          <int>        <int> <chr> <chr>  
#1 1_brown          855         2021 A     Big    
#2 1_brown          850         2019 A     Big    
#3 2_brown          852         2021 A     New Big
#4 2_brown          848         2020 A     New Big
#5 3_brown          851         2021 D     Dead   
#6 3_brown          850         2020 A     Dead   
#7 4_brown          620         2018 D     Dead   
#8 4_brown          580         2015 A     Dead
```

**data**

```
poultry <- structure(list(Bird_ID = c("1_brown", "1_brown", "2_brown", "2_brown", 
"3_brown", "3_brown", "4_brown", "4_brown"), weight_grams = c(855L, 
850L, 852L, 848L, 851L, 850L, 620L, 580L), Year_weighed = c(2021L, 
2019L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L, 2020L, 2018L, 2015L), Alive = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Much appreciated